# How Leela Zero (new chess engine) works?

Tags: neural-network, chess, monte-carlo-tree-search

Is there a **simple explanation** for dummies like me? I know that there's a source code of Leela, I've heard that it uses neural networks with MCTS (plus UCT), but there are lot of hard things remaining. Do I need to train Leela myself by running it? Or do I need to download something from Internet? (so-called trained data?) If so, do I need constantly update this data? Does it play stronger with every game?

Thank you much for advance.

Comment: https://chess.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your answer

Comment: You should post this question on chess stackexchange, or a Leela support channel, not stackoverflow